# How to acquire and use salvage droids

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I keep seeing these posts about salvage droids
and the game keeps talking about it 
but I don't see them anywhere in the game

can someone lmk how to get them and use them?

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

1) Make sure you've updated the game to the latest version.  There was a splash screen talking about the event in the previous version but it doesn't take effect until you update the app.  You may need to restart the app as well.

2) There should then be a new Salvage Droid level below the Arrivals level, next to the Imperial assignments level.  Visiting there is where to start for the salvage droid tasks.